# Add imageview and texview for each menu item in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I want to add an imageview and texview in each item of navigation drawer (like a cart image(Imageview) and items added in cart(Textview))

[image]

Comment: And your question is? Welcome to Stack Overflow. https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve will help you to understand how to ask good questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution, just needed to add **app:actionLayout** in each of my menuItem and pass the layout in it.

And you can instantiate each of the widgets using

```
navigationView.getMenu().findItem(menuitemId).getActionView().findViewById(widgetId)
```

Answer (score 0):

This thing known as badge view

[**Library Link**](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/715)

[image]

Comment: I also know about android badge but how do I add it in my menuitem??

Comment: you can inflate you own view as toolbar design and use it.

Comment: you are not getting my question.. how can I add it in menu item?

Comment: look here coussom toolbar http://sourcey.com/android-custom-centered-actionbar-with-material-design/

Comment: its not about the toolbar its about the navigationdrawer

Comment: who told you its about navigation drawer? and toolbar can apply to any activity.

Comment: I need to add that image+text in navigation drawer  **not in toolbar**

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it using RecyclerView. Take a look at these series of tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wq2o4EbM74k

Answer (score 0):

Lets first define titles and icons of the navigation drawer . So open your projects strings.xml file and add two string arrays .

After that we design xml of item of the navigation drawer. This layout is inflated every time we add a new item in the navigation drawer .

check this link i hope is usefull for you:https://androidbelieve.com/material-navigation-drawer-with-header/